# Print out part of a string from file, from start-sequence to stop-sequence

Tags: c#, string

This is my first question here, so I apologize if I break some rules. I also apologize for my mediocre English.

My assignment is to write to a file from another file using a string. It needs to print out everything between a start sequence and a stop sequence, and disregard everything else. It should also count all characters, words and number of messages, but only between start and stop. The start sequence is ASCII 27(ESC) AND ASCII 02(STX) and stop is 27 AND 02.

So my problem is that there is up to separate messages in one string. One or two, no problem, but I don't know how to find multiple sequences.

If there is just one or two, I can use string.IndexOf(start/stop) and LastIndexOf(). I have tried string[] array =string.Split() to run throug the whole string, but then I split up the sequences.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Sorry for a question with no code, but I just started over in a fury of frustration. If I did something wrong here, please give me some feedback so I can phrase it better next time :)

Comment: Not sure to understand where the problem lies. Please give a sample sequence and the desired result.

Comment: What about iterating through the file a character at a time? When you hit a start character, fill a buffer, when you hit an end character flush the buffer. That's pretty much how lexers work and if you open the file as a stream you can use almost no memory compared to reading the whole file into memory

Answer (score 1):

Try [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) of `String.Split`:

```
public string[] Split(
    string[] separator,
    StringSplitOptions options
)
```

I tried something like:

```
string test = "blah blah blahtestblah blahtestblah";
string[] splits = test.Split(new string[] { "test" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int nMessages = splits.Length;
int nWords = 0, nLetters = 0;

foreach (string str in splits)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);

    nWords += str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    nLetters += str.Length;
}
Console.WriteLine("That was {0} messages in {1} words and {2} letters", nMessages, nWords, nLetters);
```

Now that counts **all characters** except the delimiters. Also this removes blanks and does not consider them messages, and blank words as well (as in the case of a double-space). Perhaps you consider `""` a message...if so, don't use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Comment: string[] splits = test.Split(new string[] { startsequence, stopsequence }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); Is this correct?
Only problem im getting is that I get the characters before and after the sequences, in separate messages? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I would think you'd use `new string[] { "" + stopsequence + startsequence}` to separate them, then use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove `startsequence` and `stopsequence` singly.

Answer (score 1):

Tomas,

Not sure if this the best way, but should get you what you need.

```
const char startChar = (char)27;
const char stopChar = (char)02;

String yourInputString = "asfsdfpasdfiasdfoaisfpaosfiapsfoi";

byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(yourInputString);

List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();

for (int i = 0; i < yourInputString.Length; i++)
{
    switch (Convert.ToChar(array[i]))
    {
        case startChar:
            if (buffer.Count> 0)
                WriteBufferToFile(buffer);
            buffer.Add(array[i]);
            break;


        case stopChar:
            buffer.Add(array[i]);
            WriteBufferToFile(buffer);
            break;

        default:
            buffer.Add(array[0]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,